# How to reduce DNS server latency?

Tags: domain-name-system, latency

Which is the best practise to reduce DNS latency? I'm using the beautiful powerdns DNS server, and i would like to lower down latency between internet client requests and the DNS server response.

I know that working on the DNS zone backend (I'm using mysql) is one of the steps to follow to improve latency, but I'm courious to know if there is also a good rule of thumb to make DNS system resolving lightening fast.

Rising the cache TTL for DNS records is the only solution? Thank you.

Comment: I think someone should explain why voted to "close" this question. Clicking "close" without explain why is not good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you want to make your DNS server answer queries in as little time as possible, I would stay away from an RDBMS backend. When the creators of [bind](http://www.isc.org/software/bind/) decided to load DNS zone files into a purpose-built database-like structure in RAM at daemon startup instead of using an external database, they were on to something good!

If you like the convenience of having your zone data in MySQL, then you can use powerdns as a stealth master, bind servers as slaves, and publish NS records only for the bind servers.

Comment: Very good point. I'll try to use bind as DNS frontend and let you know. Thanks.